# Better way to check Contains in Moq 'It.Is<string>()' argument matchers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am mocking a method which is calling database. The method have one parameter which is SQL query to execute.

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    List<string> GetDataToList(string query);
}

public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    public List<string> GetDataToList(string query)
    {
        // Db call
    }
}
```

The mocked method is called 2 or 3 times with different queries as parameter. Due to some logic there is no specific order by which queries will be executed.

Unit test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnitTestCase
{
   Mock<IDataAccess> mock = Mock<IDataAccess>();

   List<string> data1 = new List<string>();
   mock.Setup(x =>  
   x.GetDataToList(It.Is<string(
   s => s.Contains("select * from table")))).Returns(data1);


   List<string> data2 = new List<string>();
   mock.Setup(x =>  
   x.GetDataToList(It.Is<string(
   s => s.Contains("select * from table1")))).Returns(data2);
}
```

Now as per the unit test code mocked method will be called 2 times and since there is no order and both SQL queries have some common part, `Contains` in the `SetUp` method is taking the first call only. Due to which for both the calls `data1` list is being returned.

How to avoid this issue?

Comment: For `"select * from table1"` or data access in general use integration tests against actual or in-memory database.

Comment: @Fabio: I am not hitting the DB thats why mocked the method having the DB call.

Comment: When `"select * from table1"` get passed into an abstraction(interface) that will destroy all abstraction benefits.

Comment: @KennyG, but maybe you should hit a database for this tests? Tests against actual database will provide much more valuable feedback then mocking.

Comment: I can use only table or table1 also in contains just to check for which table the call was made but that case also contains will behave in that way only. And in my case I cant hit the database to get the data.

Comment: Fabio already I am hitting Db for getting some generic or common data which is used to create the queries for each different table. I have lots of tables and then I cant hit the db each time to get the data for each table.

Comment: Why not, it is not you, but application will hit a database and now days applications are pretty quick to do it ;)

Comment: Are those queries that are passed in as parameters hard coded in the logic that's being tested? If so, that may be something to extract out from the logic, providing the benefit of having more control in the unit tests

Answer (score 0):

If you use your code it could be tricky, bacause

```
select * from table1
```

already contains

```
select * from table
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so basicly you can add `select * from table t` to this statement or just add space to Contains method

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnitTestCase
{
    Mock<IDataAccess> mock = 
    Mock<IDataAccess>();

    List<string> data1 = new List<string>();
    mock.Setup(x =>  
    x.GetDataToList(It.Is<string(
    s => s.Contains("select * from table ")))).Returns(data1); <======= (here)


    List<string> data2 = new List<string>();
    mock.Setup(x =>  
    x.GetDataToList(It.Is<string(
    s => s.Contains("select * from table1")))).Returns(data2);
}
```

Comment: Nice comment ;)

Comment: Ya I know that, becaue of that only I am getting this issue.

Comment: @KerryG check out this solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Expression<Func<string, bool>> StartingWith(string expected) => actual => actual.StartsWith(expected);
```

allows you to write

```
myMock.Verify(m => m.Write(It.Is(StartingWith("some text"))));
```

to verify the method `Write` was called with some text.